How to have rust floating point precision during operations function identical to javascript precision?
I am currently working on a project where I am porting js code to rust. There is a reoccurring issue that occurs in certain edge cases where two floating point numbers are added together and a certain bit of precision is lost.
When precision is lost in javascript, the float is truncated. However in rust, the float is rounded. Is there some way or implementation of f64 that can modify this behavior? I essentially need the rust code to perfectly mimic the js code.
Example:
-19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125 = -27.025711059570313  //rust 
-19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125 = -27.025711059570312 //javascript

As had been noted while this was still in the staging grounds, the difference is in presentation of the result, not actual binary data. See also How does JavaScript determine the number of digits to produce when formatting floating-point values?

Both JavaScript and Rust follow the IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers and, since addition is precise, no precision is lost in the underlying binary value:
let float: f64 = -19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125;
let int = float.to_bits();
println!("{int}"); // 13851672315927986176

const buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
(new Float64Array(buf))[0] = -19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125;
console.log((new BigUint64Array(buf))[0]); // 13851672315927986176n

That binary value corresponds to the decimal -27.0257110595703125.
When it comes to formatting floats as strings, there are different defaults for precision and rounding mode, but they can be overridden.

Use arbitrary precision in Rust

You can use a .X format specifier to set the number of decimal places:
let float: f64 = -19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125;
println!("{float:.15}"); // -27.025711059570312


Use arbitrary precision and/or rounding mode in JavaScript

You could explicitly tell JavaScript to use a given precision and/or rounding mode via NumberFormat:
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 15,
    maximumFractionDigits: 15,
    // roundingMode: "..."
}).format(-19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125)); // -27.025711059570312

Note that there is a NumberFormat polyfill for pre-0.12 versions of Node.js.

Use arbitrary precision and rounding mode in Rust

You could explicitly tell Rust to use a given precision and rounding mode via rust_decimal:
use rust_decimal::prelude::*;

let d = Decimal::from_f64_retain(-19.04345703125 + -7.9822540283203125).unwrap();
println!(
    "{}",
    d.round_dp_with_strategy(15, RoundingStrategy::MidpointTowardZero)
        .normalize()
        .to_string()
); // -27.025711059570312

